# Get temperature with x and y values using FlirOneSDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, position, temperature, flir

For getting the temperature in a specific point, you need the X and Y position.

You can get the pixel position using the OnTouch event of View.IOnTouchListener, for example.

Example Code:

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
   Position_X = (int)e.GetX();
   Position_Y = (int)e.GetY();
   return true;
}
```

and OnFrameProcessed, your code would look like this:

```
public void OnFrameProcessed(RenderedImage renderedImage)
{
  if (renderedImage.InvokeImageType() == RenderedImage.ImageType.ThermalRadiometricKelvinImage)
  {
      var step = renderedImage.Width();
      var pixel = Position_X + (Position_Y * step);
      var thermalPixels = renderedImage.ThermalPixelValues();
      if (thermalPixels.Length < pixel)
      {
         pixel = thermalPixels.Length - 1;
      }
      //temperature in point
      AvgPointTemperature = (thermalPixels[pixel] / 100.0) - 273.15;
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's the best method, but it's the one I found.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Comment: Do you test in Forms or Xamarin.Android project ?

Comment: Hi Jason, it's not a question, just sharing by demonstrating a small solution to a problem that I did not find answer to before

Comment: Hi Junior, I'm working with xamarin forms, but it work in xamarin Android too.

Comment: @Tayrony Got it, I share an answer .If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey , this need [Customizing a ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage) to get X and Y from IOS or Android device.

**Android**:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("x->" + e.GetX() + "y->" + e.GetY());
    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}
```

**IOS**:

```
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
    UITouch touch = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
    CGPoint cp = touch.LocationInView(this.View);
    Console.WriteLine("x->" + cp.X + "y->" + cp.Y);
}
```